# Intellij / JDK 7 Blank Dialogs

Tags: intellij-idea

Using Intellij Idea (both 12 and 13) on Ubuntu, I very often get blank dialogs.  For example, this dialog is actually showing the content in the window behind it.  I imagine that the dialog itself contains confirm Yes/No buttons.

I am running Intellij with JDK1.7.  When I run it with JDK1.6, I get a set of different problems (i.e. buttons that are cutoff).

Does anyone know if there is a fix for this?  It is starting to become disruptive and annoying

[image: Dialog]

After reloading the dialog a few times, I actually get it:

[image: Correct]

Comment: Are you using GNOME or KDE desktop?

Comment: This is Gnome on Ubuntu 13.  I switched back to JDK6, and that corrected the problem.  I guess I will live with the other problem of dialog boxes cutting off the buttons.

Comment: You should submit a bug report with JetBrains, your platform is supported, and I'm sure they would like to know if something is not working as expected: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/dashboard#newissue=yes